# .sh file when run from MAC terminal is working fine, but when run from java Java.lang.Runtime.exec() throwing error like command not found

Tags: java, node.js, macos, shell, npm

I am trying to run an `npm` command from `.sh` file. The reason I went to `.sh` file is that I do not want to append the `npm` installation location again to the PATH variable. See my file contents below,

```
echo $PATH
npm -v
```

This file runs perfect from terminal window, printing me the npm version in my macbook. However when I set the executable permission to this `.sh` file and try to run it from Java.lang.Runtime.exec(), it is giving following output - not recognizing the npm command,

```
/usr/bin:/bin/:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

... npm command not found

Although npm installation location `"/usr/local/bin"` is there in my system path - saved to bash profile, the.sh file not working from java lang process ().

Comment: How are you running from java?

Comment: Have you considered [Apache Commons Exec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/)?

Comment: Just tried, but not luck.